# Datos de horas para un Spinner

Tags: java, android

Tengo un Spinner y como datos estas horas:

```
final String[] horasInicio = new String[] {
            "09:00",
            "09:30",
            "10:00",
            "10:30",
            "11:00",
            "11:30",
            "12:00",
            "12:30",
            "13:00",
            "13:30",
            "14:00",
            "14:30",
            "15:00",
            "15:30",
            "16:00",
            "16:30",
            "17:00",
            "17:30",
            "18:00",
            "18:30",
            "19:00",
            "19:30",
            "20:00",
            "20:30"
    };
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que si son, por ejemplo, las 11:49, se genere otro array o un ArrayList que tenga los datos del spinner que serían 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30... así hasta las 20:30. Si son las 13:12, pues generar una lista con los datos 13:30, 14:00, 14:30... hasta las 20:30. son las horas de inicio de reservas, por eso si son las 11:49, lo lógico, es que la primera hora de reserva sea las 12:00 y como se puede reservar de media hora en media hora, vaya 12:00, 12:30...20:30.

Comment: No acabo de entender el problema. Es decir, si te seleccionar 11.49 quieres seleccionar el SIGUIENTE elemento válido en el array y guardar todos los siguientes elementos en un nuevo array?

Comment: Tampoco acabo de entender el problema. ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: @Red Hola Red tu pregunta la marcaron para ser cerrada, se más especifico, yo tampoco entiendo lo que deseas, como comenta Vicky, que quieres lograr ?

Comment: Hola, perdón por no ser más especifico. Me refiero a que si son las 11:49, se genere otro array o un ArrayList que tenga los datos del spinner que serían 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30... así hasta las 20:30. Si son las 13:12, pues generar una lista con los datos 13:30, 14:00, 14:30,.... hasta las 20:30. Son las horas de inicio de reservas, por eso si son las 11:49, lo lógico, es que la primera hora de reserva sea las 12:00 y como se puede reservar de media hora en media hora, vaya 12:00, 12:30, 13:00...20:30. Espero, ahora sí, haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Yo de una forma lo haria es coger la hora 12:00 y pasarla numerico y en un arraylist con las reservas tambien numerico, con un condicional sabras cual es la próxima reserva.
Ten en cuenta que si son las 21:00 no hay reserva, no ser si te interesa especificar las 12:00 del próximo dia...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haria de la siguiente manera, antes de guardar las horas en `string` las tendria en `int`

```
final int[] horasInicio = new int[] { 900, 930, 1000, 1030, 1100, 1130, 1200, 1230, 1300, 1330, 1400, 1430, 1500, 1530, 1600, 1630, 1700, 1730, 1800, 1830, 1900, 1930, 2000, 2030 };

List<Integer> horasReserva = new ArrayList<>();


int hora = 1149; 

//obtener una lista con las reservas posibles
for (int i=0;i < horasInicio.length;++i) {
    if (hora < horasInicio[i])  horasReserva.add(horasInicio[i]);
}

//mostrar las reservas
for (int i=0;i < horasReserva.size();++i) {
    System.out.println(horasReserva.get(i));
}
```

Solo queda la parte de convertir `11:49` a `int` y de `int` a formato `00:00`

Otra manera más consistente seria convertir las horas a total de minutos.